# Multi condition filtering in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have dataframe cannot show the whole data(confidential) which have a longitudes & latitudes points all  around the world but I need to filter for just one country

suppose this is data

[image]

Now I have to filter rows data for a specific country which have co-ordinates ranges this

```
`latitude` :  8°4′ N to 37°6′ N
`longitude` : 68°7′ E to 97°25′ E
```

so I tried this

```
df_filtered = df[38 > df['LATITUDE'] > 8 and 98 > df['LATITUDE'] > 68]
```

but this is giving this weird error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: df[df.a.between(8,38) & df.a.between(68,98)]

Comment: While this is correct @WeNYoBen since OP is asking for it, the `|` operator would make more sense

Comment: No worries guys,thanks for sharing the duplicate post link `df_filtered = df.loc[(df['LATITUDE'] >=8) & (df['LATITUDE'] <=38) & (df['LONGITUDE'] >=68) & (df['LONGITUDE'] <=98)]` this worked

Comment: @Saurabh your logic does not make sense: `df_filtered = df.loc[((df['LATITUDE'] >=8) & (df['LATITUDE'] <=38)) | ((df['LONGITUDE'] >=68) & (df['LONGITUDE'] <=98))` This makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

use between

```
df_filtered = df[(df['LATITUDE'].between(8,38) ) &  (df['LONGITUDE'].between(68,98))]
```

Comment: This is wrong, did you check this?

Comment: Yeah, this is giving the same error

Comment: @Saurabh it should work

Comment: @Erfan yes i have checked it